# Selenium Edge Browser extremely slow

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I am using *Selenium 3.0.0* on *Java*, I am working on *Windows 10 machine OS build - 10586.753*.

I have to automate my website on *Edge* browser and I am facing extreme slowness.

Below is my browser code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","Path to the EdgeDriverServer");       
dc = DesiredCapabilities.edge();       
driver = new EdgeDriver(dc);
```

I have downloaded the correct version of EdgeDriver based on the OS build.

I am not sure if there is any other set up that i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `pageLoadStrategy=eager`in your browser capabilities.
It makes the driver try to interact with the page as soon as the DOM is loaded (basically when the user would be able to start doing things) but it may have a negative impact on your tests if they rely on "late" events.